# why cant i search for a word in my text file?

Tags: c++

my program takes input from the user and compares it to one of the words in a text file. this was my attempt but `permitted_from_database` always returns a true regardless of what the user has typed in.

````
  ifstream database("user_details.txt");
  ifstream fin("user_data");
  while (getline(database, loginspasswords)) {
    if (loginspasswords.find(this_attempt)) {
      permitted_from_database = true;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
  database.close();
}```
````

Comment: can you please post what the contents of database and this_attempt

Comment: Are you the same person who [submitted this question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59292230/10077)?

Comment: @CyberStems database just a words listed down and this_attempt is a string that the user enters

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing the return value of find with string::npos. find does not return a boolean.